# Unable to get video to show in simulator and device (but the audio plays) Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to clone an Instagram-like app in Xcode for practice. I have images working just fine. However I can't get the video to show, but I can hear the audio when I run the simulator on the computer and on my iPhone. When I scroll to where the video should be, only the audio plays.

The files are coming from an AWS S3 bucket, I've tried both mov and mp4 files, both have the same result. Also, in the console there's this printed message:
[plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x600002daec80>

```
import SwiftUI
import AVKit

struct ItemRowView: View {
let item: LineItem

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        HStack {
            VStack {
                Text(item.name)
                    .font(.title2)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .padding()
                VStack {
                    if item.video != nil {
                        let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: item.video ?? "")!)
                        VideoPlayer(player: player)
                                    .onAppear() {
                                        player.play()
                                        player.preventsDisplaySleepDuringVideoPlayback = true
                                    }
                                    .onDisappear {
                                        player.pause()
                                    }
                        
                    } else {
                        AsyncImage(url: URL(string: item.picture ?? "")) { image in
                            image.resizable()
                                      .scaledToFit()
                        } placeholder: {
                            ProgressView()
                        }
                        .transition(.opacity.combined(with: .scale))
                        Text(item.description)
                    }
                }
                
            }
            .padding(.bottom)
        }
    }
}
}
struct ItemRowView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
    ItemRowView(item: LineItem.testLineItems[1])
}
}
```

I'm new to Swift, coding in general, I see quite a few solutions using ViewControllers, but I'm using the MVVM project structure and have no idea how to put any of those solutions to use.

Comment: The `AddInstanceForFactory` debug message is a red herring - not relevant. What probably *is* relevant is what the frame of the video player is. If you put a border around it, is it being rendered at the size you expect?

Comment: That did it, in previews the frame was automatically there so I assumed it would be the same way when I launched the app. Thank you!